# How can I add more colors to color picker component palet? (Adobe Flash/Animate)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, color-picker, adobe-animate

I want to add more colors as in the basic Adobe Animate Color Picker component color palet (see picture), but I dont't know how. Currently I only have this code:

Re-imagined new color picker:
[image]

This is my code:

```
import fl.events.ColorPickerEvent;
import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
import fl.controls.ColorPicker;

mpicker.selectedColor=0x000000;
var mcolor:ColorTransform=new ColorTransform();
mpicker.addEventListener(ColorPickerEvent.CHANGE,ccolor)
function ccolor(e:ColorPickerEvent)
{
    mcolor.color=mpicker.selectedColor;
    box.transform.colorTransform=mcolor;
}
```

Would be nice if someone could help me.
Thanks

Comment: Maybe this? https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-color-picker-in-flash--active-2378

Comment: PS: You can try setting the `columnCount` (number of down-lines) by using `mpicker.setStyle("columnCount", 18); `. The default value is 18 (count 'em) and change **18** for whatever you need.